# Why are CSV files not being created from df? (even though the code is running without error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, export-to-csv

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
PREFIX = "/Users/test/Desktop/2022-selected"
filenames = [path.split("/")[-1] for path in glob.glob(PREFIX + "123456/*.csv")]
for filename in filenames:
    filepath = f"{PREFIX}*/{filename}"
    print(filepath)
    csv_paths = glob.glob(filepath)
    df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f, header = 0) for f in csv_paths), ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv(f"{PREFIX}output_{filename}", index=False)
```

I am trying to concatenate different .csv files across folders (e.g., in code it is 123456) into new aggregated .csv files. Even though my code is running without error, the .csv files are not being written. Please help!

Comment: What is ```csv_paths```?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you added an ***/*** at the end of *PREFIX* . :)

Comment: Where in the code after PREFIX? where I am defining it or in filenames/filepath?

Comment: In the variable PREFIX itself. You are actually creating the files in your Desktop folder because of a missing `/`.

Comment: @itprorh66 it is a list of names of csv files in PREFIX location with name folders like 123456